How to enable logging in Google Cloud Go SDK
The following relatively simple snippet of code leverages the Google Cloud SDK to list all enabled services
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"

    serviceusage "cloud.google.com/go/serviceusage/apiv1"
    "cloud.google.com/go/serviceusage/apiv1/serviceusagepb"
    "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
    apitransport "google.golang.org/api/transport"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, _, err := apitransport.NewHTTPClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    loggingTransport := &logTransport{client.Transport}
    opts := option.WithHTTPClient(&http.Client{
        Transport: loggingTransport,
    })

    projectId := "FILL_IN"
    listServices(ctx, projectId, opts)
}

func listServices(ctx context.Context, projectId string, opts ...option.ClientOption) {
    c, err := serviceusage.NewClient(ctx, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer c.Close()

    it := c.ListServices(ctx, &serviceusagepb.ListServicesRequest{
        Parent: "projects/" + projectId,
        Filter: "state:ENABLED",
    })
    for {
        resp, err := it.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        log.Println(resp.Name)
    }
}

If I extract the part which interacts with the service API, it works without any problem and lists the services as expected:
    c, err := serviceusage.NewClient(ctx, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer c.Close()

    it := c.ListServices(ctx, &serviceusagepb.ListServicesRequest{
        Parent: "projects/" + projectId,
        Filter: "state:ENABLED",
    })
    for {
        resp, err := it.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        log.Println(resp.Name)
    }

However, I'd like to have logging in place to be able to inspect the HTTP requests and responses which the SDK is making/receiving. Hence I tried adding an HTTP client with a custom transport which does exactly that.
For some reason however, I keep hitting an error when I attempt to run the above code:
WithHTTPClient is incompatible with gRPC dial options

The error corresponds to these LOC in the SDK
I'm not interacting with any gRPC API, the majority of Google Cloud APIs are REST (not gRPC) I believe, and I did not set any gRPC specific options myself. I'm assuming there are such options being set somewhere by default by the SDK.
How could I possibly get around this limitation/error?

I'm also open to alternative ways of enabling such logging - i.e. such that do not involve setting custom transport and HTTP client.

Consider using NewRESTClient. Many (all?) Google's services are gRPC internally and historically exposed as REST only but increasingly as gRPC too (see Google APIs)

There remains your good question as to how to generically log REST and gRPC calls.

@DazWilkin That does solve my immediate need indeed, I completely missed that function - Thanks for pointing it out! Agreed about the need to generically log both.
